# Are all hiriqs the same or is there a distinction if a yud or other silent letter follows?

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, pronunciation, vowels-nekudot

For example, what would be the difference in pronunciation of the hiriq in these two words: נִקּוּד and תִּינוֹק?

What about רִאשׁוֹן? Is it "Rishon" similar to "pit" or "Reeshon" similar to "pizza"?

Preferably I would like to receive answers for both ashkenazi and sefardi pronunciations which would aid in the recitation of the daily prayers.

Comment: Grammatically one is a "long vowel" and one is a "short vowel". Whether or not you distinguish those in pronunciation is another story.

Comment: @Double please elaborate. Do you mean it's not necessary to, or just that most people don't?

Comment: @DoubleAA, what makes the hiriq a long vowel?

Comment: @AniYodea Traditionally, there are two different 'hiriq' vowels: the long one is _usually_ denoted with a yud after it, while the short on is _usually_ denoted without it.

Comment: So I guess that would make the hiriq in rishon a short vowel.

Comment: @AniYodea Right, but I said "usually" for a reason :)

Comment: Are Hebrew questions not off-topic?

Comment: @CashCow unless they are related to Judaism.

Comment: @CashCow Hebrew doesn't make a question on-topic. Judaism does, no matter what language is being discussed in the Judaism-question.